# Uploading object images before saving the object to the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, file-upload

I have a car form which includes several properties and two buttons:
first button is to save the car properties form
second one is to upload the photos of the car

the problem is that the photos table has carId property 
and when this car is not saved then the carId will be null
if the user tries to upload cars before saving the car properties  an error comes 
if he saved the car portieres he get redirected to the main page and photos will not be uploaded

code to upload images

```
public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile(int carId)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(carId);
        bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
        string fName = "";
        try
        {
            foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                //Save file content goes here
                if (file != null)
                {
                    fName = file.FileName;
                    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {

                        var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo($"{Server.MapPath(@"\")}Images");

                        var pathString = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "carimages");

                        var isExists = Directory.Exists(pathString);

                        if (!isExists)
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                        var path = $"{pathString}\\{fName}";
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                        var image = new PhotoUpload()
                        {
                            Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fName),
                            Extension = Path.GetExtension(fName),
                            CarId = id
                        };
                        _context.PhotoUploads.Add(image);
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            isSavedSuccessfully = false;
        }


        if (isSavedSuccessfully)
        {
            return Json(new { Message = fName });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file" });
        }
    }
```

code to save car

```
public ActionResult Save(CarDto carDto)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new 
Uri("http://localhost:54490") };

        switch (carDto.Id)
        {
            case 0:
                var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                carDto.CarOwnerId = id;
                client.PostAsJsonAsync<CarDto>("Api/cars", carDto)
                    .ContinueWith((postTask) => 
 postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
                break;
            default:

                client.PutAsJsonAsync<CarDto>("Api/cars", carDto)
                    .ContinueWith((postTask) => 
postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
                break;

        }

        return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index", "Manage", new
        {
            id = 1,
            tab = "myCars"
        }));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you maybe upload the images regardless under a temp folder and return a GUID that represent the temp folder? when all is well, move the photos to the folder you would like them to be at, this way, you can always link your photos to your carId when the user saves the car.

Or you can enable the upload photos button only when there is a valid carID that is greater than zero(assuming you using identity(1,1) fro your datatabse , or some guid)

Comment: thanks for answering
could you plz give an example for that